# How to spread words in several lines uniformly?

Tags: tex-core, line-breaking, paragraphs

In TeX, I can use

```
\hbox to 1in{foo bar baz}
```

to get
[image]

Is it possible generalize the use, to get this result:

[image]

by typing a paragraph `foo bar baz test text only`?

I tried `\break` to break lines at the end of the paragraph, or to set `\parfillskip=0pt`, but the results are wrong:

[image]

What parameters should be set to tell TeX's line-breaking algorithm to get this 'ugly' result?

Comment: Could e-TeX's `\lastlinefit` be relevant here?

Comment: @morbusg: I don't think so. As is said in eTeX's manual, the new algorithm is used only if '`\parfillskip` has infinite stretchability'. But I need it to be `0pt` here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\parbox{1in}{\sloppy\parfillskip=0pt
foo bar baz test text only}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, works up to `1.4in` (for `1.5in`, everything fits into one line).

Comment: Great! `\tolerance10000` and `\parfillskip0pt` does the work.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing very general springs to mind. You're going to need to convince TeX that the two lines you want are better than what it gives you. This does it for your particular example.

```
\hsize1in
\parfillskip0pt
\parindent0pt
\fontdimen3\font.25in
foo bar baz test text only
\bye
```

It is setting the font dimension parameter 3—the amount of stretch for a normal space—in the current font to one quarter of an inch.

I guess this sort of works for larger text. Using `\frenchspacing` to have intersentence spacing be the same as interword spacing and removing the size, it produces something more or less reasonable (I think; I'm not sure what your exact requirements are).

```
\parfillskip0pt
\parindent0pt
\fontdimen3\font.25in
\frenchspacing
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do
eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
\bye
```

[image: lorem ipsum]

Comment: Thank you. `\frenchspacing` is useful. But setting larger `\fontdimen3` may not produce uniform spacing. It seems that TeX will still try to get pretty line-breaking with fewer streching and shrinking.