# TikZ: How to use flushleft and flushrigt inside a 'nodepart' of the shape 'rectangle split'

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I make some text flushleft and some other text flushrigt inside a 'nodepart' of the shape 'rectangle split':

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{book} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary {shapes.multipart}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
\node[
rectangle split, rectangle split parts=3,
draw, anchor=center,
minimum size=25mm, inner sep=2pt, 
]{
first 
\nodepart{second}  left    right
\nodepart{third} third
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The old school solution is to add `\hfill` (or `\hspace*{\fill}`) where a gap is needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're setting a `minimum width` and can ensure that the node is actually not wider than that, you can set a `text width` dependent on it and apply [How to spread words in several lines uniformly?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12513/16595).

Since PGF/TikZ lets TeX do all the typesetting of the text of nodes you will have to use its methods for any text spacing. (And using `text width` delegates this to TeX because TikZ simply installs a `minipage` inside the node text.)

### Code

```
\documentclass[]{book} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  align/spread/.code=\def\tikz@text@action{\parfillskip=0pt},
  spread across minimum width/.style={
    text width=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/minimum width}
           -2*(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep}),
    align=spread}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\sffamily
\tikz\node[
  rectangle split, rectangle split parts=3,
  draw, anchor=center, minimum size=25mm, inner sep=2pt]{
  first 
  \nodepart[spread across minimum width]{second} left right
  \nodepart{third} third
};

\tikz\node[
  rectangle split, rectangle split parts=3,
  draw, anchor=center, minimum size=30mm, inner sep=2pt]{
  first 
  \nodepart[spread across minimum width]{second} left middle right
  \nodepart{third} third
};
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
\node[
rectangle split, rectangle split parts=3,
draw, align=center,     % <----
text width=25mm,        % <----
inner sep=2pt,
]{
first
\nodepart{second}  left\hfill   right
\nodepart{third} third
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:**
Since you persist to not use `text width` option in your multi part node, below is alternative, more complex way:

```
\documentclass[]{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary {shapes.multipart}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
\node (n) [
rectangle split, rectangle split parts=3,
draw, align=center,     % <----
minimum size=25mm,       
inner sep=2pt,
]{
first
\nodepart{second} \vphantom{fg} 
\nodepart{third} third
};
\node[right] at (n.two west) {left};
\node[left]  at (n.two east) {right};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
With implicit use of the `text width`, which is now used as `nodepart` option and calculated from minimum width of node. Inspired by Qrrbrbirlbel answer (+1 for `align/spread/.code` !)

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}

\tikzset{
        VMPN/.style = {rectangle split, rectangle split parts=3,
                       draw, anchor=center,
                       minimum size=25mm, inner sep=2pt,
                       text width=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/minimum width}
                            -2*(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep}),
                        align=center}, % for my addendum
        }

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
\node (n) [VMPN]{first
                 \nodepart{second} left\hfill right
                 \nodepart{third} third
                 };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result is the same as in the first example.

Comment: Is there a way without 'text width'?

Comment: Don't think so: what shall happen with 1 word, 2 words, 3 words etc.? Best control is via "good old LaTeX typesetting" when it comes to text, in my view. // Certainly you can determine the data of the node of interest, and overwrite it somehow ... but ... it's a longer route.

Comment: @cis, no so simple. alternative way is added to answer. What is wrong with`\textwidth`?